# Display grid positioning

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a website like this, I want the explore button to be more on the right end and I'm trying to do it with a grid.

[! [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpgtI.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpgtI.jpg)

**html**

```
    <div class="container space-txt flex grid-container even-columns" style="max-width: 60rem;">
        <div class="container">
            <h4>SO, YOU WANT TO TRAVEL TO</h4>
            <h1>SPACE</h1>
            <p>Let’s face it; if you want to go to space, you might as well genuinely go to outer space and not
                hover
                kind of on the edge of it. Well sit back, and relax because we’ll give you a truly out of this world
                experience!</p>

        </div>
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="btn" style="margin-top: 5rem" >
                <!-- explore button -->
                <a href="#" class="large-button uppercase ff-serif fs-600 text-dark bg-white">Explore</a>
            </div>


        </div>

    </div>

</header>
```

**css code**

```
.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 10em repeat(2, minmax(0, 40rem)) 2em;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
display:flex;
background-color:blue;
}

.btn {
margin-left:auto
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<button class="btn">explore</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

By using the above code you can achieve this, no need to use grid you can achieve this with the help of flex. set the parent as display: flex and child with margin-left:auto